# Closing file descriptor while performing ioctl

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, kernel-module, file-descriptor

I'm writing a Linux Kernel Module, and my userland app is looping on a parallel `ioctl` call (to get info from the kernel module). But when I want to close the file descriptor (linked to my kernel module), the `release` function is not executed until the `ioctl` function has not exited.

I can't find anything on why it behaves like that. Do you have an idea on why it happens, and how I can avoid this blocking ? I'd basically like to have my `ioctl` and `close` functions being executed simultaneously in my kernel module.

Thank you ! :)

Answer (score 1):

> I'd basically like to have my `ioctl` and `close` functions being executed simultaneously in my kernel module.

You cannot.

Calling `.release()` method means that the **file object isn't used** anymore. So it cannot be executed while `ioctl` for given file is in progress.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So do you know how I'm supposed to implement the behavior I want ?

Comment: As the answer states, you **cannot** observe `.ioctl()` and `.release()` executed at the same time. What else do you want from me?

Comment: I meant : do you have an idea of what could be a better design ? For example, I am allowed to execute concurrent calls to `ioctl` ?

Comment: Yes, you may execute `ioctl` concurrently.